# How to Improve a Distance Model

Tags: arcgis-10.0, distance, modelbuilder, modelling

I am working on a distance model that creates distance rings around a given point and assigns those rings a probability. The point is in the center of a 25 x 25 km area, and the model fails to assign a probability to the area that is outside of the rings but inside the 25 x 25 km area. How can I build a simple model in model-builder where I can merge the two layers together and assign probability to the area that is not included in the model? The probability that I want to assign to the outside area is 5%.

Comment: Probably should have asked before answering - are you using raster or vector data?

Comment: It is a vector data that I will later convert into a raster

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Feature Evelope to Polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000038000000) tool to create the 25km square. Calculate the probabilities for the rings as previously (I assume with [Multiple Ring Buffer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001p000000)) and then [Union](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000s000000) them with the 25km square - this will leave null values for the regions of the square outside the rings. Then simply calculate a new probability over the nulls using [Calculate Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004m000000).

Comment: How can I calculate the field value of only one polygon using the calculate field? I don't want it to change the field values for my other rings...

Comment: Either make a selection using [Make Feature Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006p000000) and then calculate the field, or use an expression in Calculate Field so it ignores existing values - something like `0.05 if !probability_field! is None else !probability_field!`